# How to open multiple Json files and save them in multiple variables

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have some Json files. The naming convention of the file is `dataset_ML-Model_params.json`. For example, `House_Lasso_params.json`,
`House_RF_params.json`, `Bike_Lasso_params.json`, and `Bike_RF_params.json`.

All of these files contains `tuning-hyperparameters` in dict format. I can open 1 file using the below code

```
filename = f"{args.dataset}_Lasso_params.json"
    outfile = HT_OUT / filename
    with open(outfile, "r") as file:
        d_loaded = json.load(file)
```

Passing the value to the model.

```
Lasso(**d_loaded, precompute=True)
```

Again for another file

```
filename = f"{args.dataset}_RF_params.json"
    outfile = HT_OUT / filename
    with open(outfile, "r") as file:
        rf_loaded = json.load(file)

RF(**rf_loaded)
```

Here, `args.dataset` contains the `dataset` name. Could you tell me, how can I load these 2 files and save them in different variables. So that later i can pass the variable to the model. Like

```
# After opening and saving the json file in different variable
Lasso(**lasso_params, precompute=True)
RF(**rf_params)
```

Comment: Why not simple move the code of passing the the parameters to the values after you've read all files? Or are you seeking a more generic solution when you have a lot of files?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have a lot of files. So, I wanted some pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of all models

```
MODEL_NAMES = ["Lasso", "Ridge"]
```

Make another dictionary to save the params for each model

```
    models_params = {}
    for model_name in MODEL_NAMES:
        filename = f"{args.dataset}_{model_name}_params.json"
        outfile = HT_OUT / filename
        with open(outfile, "r") as file:
            d_loaded = json.load(file)
            models_params[model_name] = d_loaded
```

Later, use the `get(key)` to access your expected params.

```
Lasso(**(models_params.get('Lasso')), precompute=True)
RF(**(models_params.get('RF')))
```

You can also check the params

```
print(Lasso(**(models_params.get('Lasso')), precompute=True).get_params())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use another dict that gonna contain params that you need.
For example,

```
model_params = {'lasso_params': smth_here, 'rf_params': smth_here}
```

So then you can get needed value by

```
*model_params['lasso_params']
```

To get all files by that wildcard (dataset_ML-Model_params.json.) you could use library called glob:

```
from glob import glob

glob('*_params.json') # return ['lasso_params', 'rf_params', ...]
```

And then just read them one by one.